# color bar chart if by condition if values exist?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2023,2023],
    'source': ['youtube', 'youtube', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google', 'google'], 
             'score': [10,20,100,200,300,90,70], 
             'rating': ['small', 'large', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'medium', 'large']})
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart for each of the different **source values** - so there will be 3 plots, one for each of the values in the source column.

I am trying to set colors for the bar charts via a colors mapping argument in `df.plot` - but not all the values appear e.g. youtube for 2022 does not have a value for **medium** hence the color mapping causes an error.

here is my color mapping:

```
color_map = {'small': 'yellow', 'medium': 'green', 'large':'blue'}
```

How can i ensure that when making the plots there is no error and it handles missing cases fine?

My code for plot is below:

```
for company in df['source'].unique(): 
    # filter to make plot of company only
    temp_df = df[df.source == company]
    
    temp_df = temp_df.pivot_table(index=temp_df.year, columns=['source', 'rating'], values='score', aggfunc='sum')
    
    color_map = {'small': 'yellow', 'medium': 'green', 'large':'blue'}
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
    ax = temp_df.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6), ylabel='scores', xlabel='dates', title='Scores', ax = ax,color = color_map)
```

Comment: `g = sns.displot(data=df, x='source', weights='score', multiple='stack', hue='rating', col='year')` is much cleaner, and it's only a single of code. In any case, seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFui.png)

Comment: Or `g = sns.displot(data=df, x='source', weights='score', multiple='stack', hue='rating', col='year', palette=['y', 'b', 'g'])` for the different colors.

Comment: While _stack bars_ are used (too often), they make it more difficult to compare values. It is visually, and from an interpretation perspective, to use grouped bars that are not stacked.

Comment: Or with year on the x-axis (ignore the red warnings, that's because of my pandas version, relative to seaborn). [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1JqE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pivoting your DataFrame, fill any missing values with zeros. This ensures that any combination of year, source, and rating that doesn't exist in the original DataFrame will have a zero value in the pivoted DataFrame.
As you noted, some sources might not have all ratings. So, we'll subset the `color_map` to only include colors for ratings that are present in the `temp_df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2023,2023],
    'source': ['youtube', 'youtube', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google', 'google'], 
    'score': [10,20,100,200,300,90,70], 
    'rating': ['small', 'large', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'medium', 'large']
})

color_map = {'small': 'yellow', 'medium': 'green', 'large':'blue'}

for company in df['source'].unique(): 
    # filter to make plot of company only
    temp_df = df[df.source == company]
    
    # pivot the data
    temp_df = temp_df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='rating', values='score', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)

    # Get the unique ratings present in the temp_df
    present_ratings = temp_df.columns

    # Subset the color_map using only the ratings present in temp_df
    subset_color_map = {rating: color_map[rating] for rating in present_ratings if rating in color_map}

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax = temp_df.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6), ylabel='scores', xlabel='dates', title=f'Scores of {company}', ax=ax, color=[subset_color_map[r] for r in present_ratings])
    plt.legend(title='Rating')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: No categories are aggregated, as such, it should be `.pivot`, not `.pivot_table`: `temp_df = temp_df.pivot(index='year', columns='rating', values='score')`